# Function $T = x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2$ from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

The function $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ gives the temperature (in degrees) at each point in space. Suppose a particle is at the point $p = (1, 1, 1)$.

$$T = x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2$$

1. In which direction should the particle move to get the most rapid decrease in temperature? Call this direction $u$.
2. How far should the particle move away from the point $p$ in the direction of $u$ to get a decrease of $1.2$ degrees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Recall that the particle will get the most rapid increase in temperature moving towards the gradient, so it will get the greatest decrease in temperature moving away from the gradient.  $\nabla T = ( 2x , 4y , 4z )$, so with $(x,y,z) = (1,1,1)$, you should move in the negative gradient direction, namely towards $( -1,-2,-2 )$.
2. $T(p) = 5$, so you want to find $T(p + cu) = 3.8$.  $T(p+cu) = ( 1 - c )^2 + 2( 1 - 2c )^2 + 2( 1 - 2c)^2 = 3.8$ reduces the problem to a quadratic equation.  This will have two solutions: take the smallest positive solution, since that will be the one closest to the point $p$ in the direction of $u$.  Once you have that, find $( 1 , 1 , 1 ) + c ( -1 , -2 , -2 )$ to get the desired point.